# Any online resources on dongba language and hieroglyph？

Tags: writing-systems

I visited Yunnan last year and found the fascinating dongba hieroglyph of naxi people and their great epic poetry. I am curious about any online resources on this dongba hieroglyph?

I, personally, start [an amateur project](https://github.com/mountain/bor) to draw these glyph by metafont according to a dictionary I bought at Yunnan. But I was confused by

- how to label these hieroglyph with pronunciation?
- how to organize these hieroglyph by a meaningful index?
- ...

Any online resources or advices on dongba language and hieroglyph are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [纳西族象形标音文字字典](https://www.ynmyw.cn/UploadFile/XFLINFOEdit/20171121192154165.pdf) (Nàxī zú xiàng xíng biāo yīn wénzì zìdiăn) — Naxi Pictographs and Transcription Characters Dictionary, 2001, Author: 李霖灿 (Lĭ Líncàn), publisher: 云南民族出版社 (Yunnan National Publishing House), in which each Naxi pictograph has *IPA transcription and explanation in Chinese*, and there's also a part about the Geba syllabary.

The dictionary is organized semantically. There are 2120 pictograms arranged under 18 categories according to the object depicted: heavenly bodies, people, animals, plants, tools, etc.:

> 1. Hieroglyphics about phenomena connected with heaven; e. g. heaven, sun, moon, stars, wind, clouds, thunder, snow, spring, morning, darkness, blessing from heaven, forming of the universe.
> 2. Hieroglyphics about geographical phases; e. g. earth, mountain, water, lake, stone, field, way, north, south, frozen earth, mountain in fire, falling of stone.
> 3. Hieroglyphics about human natures, relatives and movements; e. g. man, woman, father, son, sovereign, friend, Chinese, I, you, lazy, cold, bitter, rich, to sit, to stand, to get, to beg, to be afraid, to make fire, to bring up a beautiful daughter.
> 4. Hieroglyphics about different parts of human body and their movements; e.g. head, face, eye, ears, hand, foot, to see, to hear, to cry, to drink, to think, to press.
> 5. Hieroglyphics about birds; e. g. cock, goose, stork, dove, bird' swing, bird' s tail, crest, to fly, to claw, to hatch eggs.
> 6. Hieroglyphics about animals and insects; e. g. tiger, lion, pig, dog, horn, hoof, butterfly, frog, fish, wine in yak's horn, to plough, to kill an ox, to scorch an animal's shoulder-blade.
> 7. Hieroglyphics about plants; e. g. tree, grass, forest, flower, seeds, poisonous flower, falling of fruits, to bend (a tree) , to cut (a tree)
> 8. Hieroglyphics about objects made and need by human beings; e. g. spade, round, to pour out, to melt, to wave, to connect, to break, black, bad, sound of to hang, to open the door.
>    pail, basket, box, plank, door, book, flag, flute, to weigh, to measure, to write,
> 9. Hieroglyphics relating to eating and drinking; e. g. vase, bowl, chopsticks, rice in bowl, soap, tea, to cook, to twin, to have something to eat, difficult (to have something to eat)
> 10. Hieroglyphics about clothes and decorative pieces; e. g. hat, dress, boots, a needle, thread, ear-ring, finger-ring, silver, gold, jade, coral, to weave, to inlay.
> 11. Hieroglyphics about weapons; e. g. knife, bow, arrow, armor, iron ax, broken lance-point, to cut, to shoot, to hammer, to cast iron, to throw stones.
> 12. Hieroglyphics about buildings, numbers, movements, etc.; e. g. village, house, tent, home, to repair a house, one, two, three, hundred, thousand, to surround, to pour out, to melt, to wave, to connect, to break, black, bad, sound of blowing a leaf.
> 13. Hieroglyphics used in the Jo-K'a district only
> 14. Hieroglyphics words phoneticized in Mo-so script, each word spelt with two Mo-so hieroglyphics.
> 15. Hieroglyphics about ceremonial rites and tools; e. g. incense-burner, bell, horn, hand-drum, charting beads, a piece of wood used for offering , to prepare a shrine, to offer a sacrifice, to give food to ghosts.
> 16. Hieroglyphics about ghosts and spirits, mostly their names.
> 17. Hieroglyphics about to-mba and Dragon King, mostly their names.
> 18. Hieroglyphics about gods, mostly their names.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongba_symbols), and also since Dongba is just a script, investigate the language that underlies it, [Naxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxi_language). [This](https://glottolog.org/resource/languoid/id/naxi1245) is a list of materials on the language. The article on Dongba explains that it is not a system for writing a language, it is a mnemonic set of symbols for reciting classical texts, so there isn't a fixed pronunciation for a given picture. The [Geba](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/naxi.htm#geba) syllabary, on the other hand, seems to have a more phonetic basis, though it is even more endangered.